# Subgroups of minimal non-abelian 2-groups

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

I want to determine all maximal subgroups of the following type of minimal non-abelian 2-group: $\langle a, b, c : a^{2^{s}} = b^2 = c^{2} = 1, [a,c] = [b,c] = 1, [a, b]=c\rangle$ of order $2^{s+2}$; $s \ge 1$. 
Every hint will be appreciate. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can calculate the  commutator subgroup $[G,G]$ (it seems not difficult). Since  all maximal subgroups of $G$ include $[G,G]$, there is a bijection between them and maximal subgroups  of $G/[G,G]$.

Comment: @ Boris Novikov
it just gives us the number of maximal subgroups which is three, but I want to distinguish them as the generators of the group.

Comment: @ shankfei: You can get the generators of maximal subgroup of $G$ as the union of generators  of maximal subgroup of $G/[G,G]$  and generators  of $[G,G]$ (of course, the obtained generating set might be reduced somehow).

Comment: Dear  Boris Novikov, we know that $\frac{G}{[G,G]}=\langle \bar{a} , \bar{b} \mid \bar{a}^{2^s}=\bar{b}^2=1, [\bar{a},\bar{b}]=1\rangle$. Now maximal subgroups of $\frac{G}{[G,G]}$ are $\langle \bar{a}\rangle$, $\langle \bar{a}^2, \bar{b}\rangle$ and $\langle \bar{a}^2, \bar{a}^2\bar{b}\rangle$. Therefore as your last comment maximal subgroups of $G$ are $\langle a , [a,b]\rangle$, $\langle a^2, b,[a,b]\rangle$ and $\langle a^2, a^2b, [a,b]\rangle$ where $\bar{a}:=a[G,G]$ and $\bar{b}:=b[G,G]$. Does this your mean?

Comment: @shankfei: Yes, now it is OK.

Comment: Dear Boris Novikov, many thanks. I just correct that the third maximal subgroup of $\bar{G}$ is $\langle \bar{a}^2 ,\bar{a}\bar{b}\rangle$. So the third maximal subgroup of $G$ is $\langle  a^2 , ab \rangle$.